# Finding the limit of a given sequence: ${a_{n}} = \frac {2^{3n}-n3^n} {n^{1729}+8^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a limit as follows

$${a_{n}} = \frac {2^{3n}-n3^n} {n^{1729}+8^n}$$

and I would like to find the limit of this sequence.

I think the limit is 1, so I tried to prove this using the squeeze rule and I am not able to do it.

Thanks to anybody who helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** as 
$$
\frac{n3^n}{8^n}\to 0
\\
\frac{n^{1729}}{8^n}\to 0
$$
the limit is $1$.

---

Details:

let us prove that $\frac{n3^n}{8^n} \le C\frac1{\sqrt n}$ for a certain $C$.
We use induction:

- if $\frac{n3^n}{8^n} \le C\frac1{\sqrt n}$ then
  $$
  \frac{(n+1)3^{n+1}}{8^{n+1}}
  = \frac{n3^n}{8^n} \times \frac 38\frac{n+1}n
  \le C\frac1{\sqrt n} \times \frac 38\frac{n+1}n
  \le C \frac1{\sqrt {n+1}}
  $$
  The last inequality is true is soon as:
  $$ C\frac 38 \left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{3/2} \le 1
  \\ \iff 
   n\ge \frac 1{    \left(\frac 8{3C}\right)^{2/3}
   - 1}
  $$
  which is always true if $C$ is large enough.
- now choose $C$ so that the inequality is true for $n=1$ as well. And you are done.

Comment: How can you prove that both of the sequences tends to 0 as n tends to infinity?

Comment: in both cases you can prove using induction that it is dominated by, say, $C/\sqrt n$ for a certain $C$. I can add details if you like.

Comment: and $2^{3n}=8^n$ to finish. Cheers :-)

Comment: @mookid Thank you for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically the exponential terms carry, i.e. $2^{3n} / 8^n = 1$  easily.